# Dynamically Populate Gravity Form Field with Page Title

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to fill in a Gravity Form field dynamically with the current page title. I should be able to do this with populate dynamically option. I am using a shortcode:

```
<?php
  $product_name = the_title();
?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="2" name="BCMac.com Product PDF Download" field_values="product_name='.$product_name.'" title="false" description="false" ajax="true" ]' ); ?>
```

When I use a static value in the shortcode, it works great. Whenever I try to output the title via the variable, it outputs it above the form and not in the field. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_title()` is a template tag that automatically echos the title and does not return a value. What you probably want is `get_the_title()`.

Comment: Of course. I should have thought of that. Thanks for your help!